# Error with Java code that finds the index of the minimum element in array

Tags: traversal

The problem is that when given an array of integers, I'm supposed to print out the index that stores the minimum value. If multiple entries in the array all store the minimum value, I should print out the minimum index.

Here is the code (in Java):

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] counts = {32, 22, 37, 16, 10, 11};
    int x = counts[0];
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < counts.length) {
        if (counts[counter] < x) 
            x = counter;
      counter++;
    }

    System.out.println(x);

  }
}
```

With this code, while the answer printed should be 4, I'm getting an answer of 2. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm setting x to counter when the current entry is less than the stored minimum value. How do I fix the error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a very small error - while you are storing the index of the minimum element correctly, when you compare the current element during your traversal to x, you are comparing the current element to the index of the current minimum rather than the current minimum itself. To fix this, you must make a very small change on line 7 to if (counts[counter] < counts[x]), and change line 4 to int x = 0;